# DI Container and controllers

Tags: php, symfony

I just followed the http://fabien.potencier.org/article/50/create-your-own-framework-on-top-of-the-symfony2-components-part-1 articles, and have some questions about the DI container.

Let's say I want to fire an event inside my controller, how would i get the dispatcher inside my controller?

I'm starting my test framework through

```
$c->get('app')->handle($request);
```

where 'app' is the Symfony\HttpKernel. How can i set the dependencies to the container? Let's say I have a view engine, defined in the container

```
$c->register('view.engine', 'Core\ViewEngine');
```

and I want to give that object, or resolve that object, inside my Controller to render some views. It's the same problem with the event fire, I don't have access to those values inside my controller ... How is a DI container supposed to work in situations like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are different approaches.  You might want to read through the silex documentation as a next step.  In silex, the application itself is a DI container.  You might also read through the introduction to Symfony 2 documentation.

The most straight forward approach (and the one used by S2 as a default) is to inject the DI container itself into your controller.  The controller can then pull out services such as the dispatcher as needed.

A "better" approach is to inject the dispatcher along with whatever else the controller needs directly into the controller.  It's "better" because the controller itself does not need access to the container.  But it's more difficult since a controller often needs a number of services just to it's job.

==============================================

**How would I inject the container in the controller though?**

That is where looking at existing frameworks starts to come in handy.  Remember that HTTPKernel is a component and not a framework.  How you use it is up to you.

In Symfony 2 the app object is actually derived from Kernel and not HTTPKernel.  The Kernel in turn contains an instance of HTTPKernel as well as an instance of the container.

There are several approaches you might take.  There is no single "correct" one.

If you look into HTTPKernel::handleRaw you will find:

```
$controller = $this->resolver->getController($request))
```

You might make your own controller resolver object which would inject the container after creating the controller.  Just one possibility.

Comment: How would I inject the container in the controller though? Since the HttpKernel is creating my controller, I can't give it through the constructor, and I have no control over the controller, since all I get in return is a response object

Comment: Drive by down vote two years after the fact.  So brave.